# zoom in at the center and scroll by dragging using CSS Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a product builder for an online store. I got the image to zoom in on hover and scroll but it scrolls to the top left. when I set the origin to center it zooms in at the center but does not scroll to the left or to the top. Also non-mac users are not able to scroll left-right with the mouse scroll wheel so I'd like to be able to scroll by dragging. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:
HTML:

```
<div id="option_image" class="rotationViewer option_image spritespin-instance" style="max-height: 544px; -webkit-user-select: none; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3600px; height: 3600px;" unselectable="on">
    <div class="spritespin-stage" style="width: 3600px; height: 3600px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; display: block; background-image: url(&quot;//www.shappify-cdn.com/images/78432/86058914/001_first-screen.png&quot;); background-size: 500px 500px; background-position: 0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    <div class="spritespin-preload" style="width: 3600px; height: 3600px; top: 0px; left: 0px; position: absolute; display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#option_image:hover {
width: 500px !important; 
height: 500px !important; 
overflow-x: auto !important; 
overflow-y: auto !important;
}
.spritespin-stage { 
transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
position: absolute !important;
}
.spritespin-stage:hover { 
margin: center;
transform: scale(5); 
transform-origin: top left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why those styles are set inline and the rules within the style tag are being set with !important.  That is specificity creep.  Also, the width of the container is being fixed inline and then clipped in a max width.  This all makes your task of debugging and refining more difficult.

A more central problem appears to be one of focus.  Your container div is not focusable. When the user hovers, any scrolling with a scroll wheel will scroll whatever element has focus if it meets the conditions for scrolling to occur.  You could give your .option_image container a tabindex attribute of zero if focusing fits the user experience you're going for.

Comment: Thanks Avram. You're absolutely correct. The full story is that I am fine-tuning a customizing app my client has purchased for their online store. This app doesnt allow me to change the html. Just lets me add in css and its extremely difficult to make things work because of the inline styling. The html you see is what i have copied from the developer tools on chrome.